# Value of an angle at the same point in a parametric curve

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives, parametric

> What is the value of $\cos\theta$ for the line defined by the parametric equation $(x, y, z)=\left(-t^2+4t+1,\:3\cos\left(\pi t\right),\:t^3-21t\right)$ at the point where it crosses itself?

So I let the two variables be $s$ and $t$. So when the line crosses itself, $t=5$ and $s=-1$. The derivative of the above equation is $\left(-2t+4,\:-3\pi \sin\left(\pi t\right),\:3t^2-21\right)$. So I plugged in the values for $s$ and $t$ and got that for $t$ the vector was $(-6, 0, 54)$ and for $s$ the vector was $(6, 0, -18)$.

So to calculate $\cos\theta$, I did the following:

$\frac{\left(-6,\:0,\:54\right)\cdot \left(6,\:0,\:-18\right)}{\sqrt{\left(-6\right)^2+\left(54\right)^2}\sqrt{6^2+\left(-18\right)^2}}$ which gave me a value of $\frac{-14}{\sqrt{205}}$, which is incorrect.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point is correct

- $-t^2+4t+1=-s^2+4s+1 \implies t^2-s^2=4(t-s) \implies t+s=4$
- $t^3-21t=s^3-21s \implies t^3-s^3=21(t-s) \implies t^2+st+s^2=21$

that is $t=5$ ans $s=-1$ and also the evaluation for the tangent vectors and the final step, indeed we obtain

$$\frac{\left(-6,\:0,\:54\right)\cdot \left(6,\:0,\:-18\right)}{\sqrt{\left(-6\right)^2+\left(54\right)^2}\sqrt{6^2+\left(-18\right)^2}}=\frac{-1008}{72\sqrt{205}}=\frac{-14}{\sqrt{205}}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I see that the value you have given is smaller than $-1$. But how can cos theta be smaller than $-1$? Your value is $-1.007$.

Comment: @sktsasus Opsss sorry there was a mistake in my derivation! I fix that.

Comment: I see. But as you can hopefully see in my post above, that is the answer I had as well. But I am being told that is incorrect. By the way, if this helps, theta is supposed to represent the acute angle between the vectors.

Comment: @sktsasus Indeed my aim was to check your result and it seems correct. What you have obtained is the value for the obtuse angle, For the acute angle it suffices to note that $\cos \theta=-\cos (\pi - \theta)$.

Comment: @sktsasus What is the given result?

Comment: Well I seem to be getting the same result by your formula. So I feel I am doing it incorrectly. Or is the value supposed to be the same?

Comment: @sktsasus For the acute angle the result is simply $\frac{14}{\sqrt{205}}$ (we reverse the direction of one vector). Maybe there is a typo in the given or in the result.

Comment: Ohhh yes you are right! Thank you for the help!

Comment: @sktsasus Then the issue was only on the sign?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. :)